# (Rails 3) Is it possible to hardcode ids in a named route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As far as I know, the following is the encouraged way to create a simple named route in Rails 3:

`match 'sign-in' => 'sessions#create', :as => :sign_in`

Is there a clean way to hardcode an id (or any parameter) in a named route? For a silly example:

`match 'first-user' => 'users#show', :as => :first_user, :id => 1`

Comment: Did you try that? It may just work.

Comment: @RyanBigg - Ugh. Incredible. While asking the question, I wrote what I felt would be the most intuitive syntax, and embarrassingly, it ended up being exactly what I needed. Please make your comment an answer, and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: I'd say that's the sign of a well-designed DSL!

Comment: Posted as an answer to follow the correct format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try that? It just works like that.

Comment: Now you can credit, not that you're particularly in need of it!